# Can I apply for a tourist Schengen visa but then cancel the hotel bookings and stay at my friend's place?

Tags: schengen, tourist-visas, schengen-visas

He lives in Utrecht, Netherlands and the Netherlands would be my port of entry and exit, as well as the country I spend the most time in. My friend would have to go through so much hassle for giving the sponsorship letter and previous salary slips.

Besides, he just had an accident a few weeks ago and hasn't been working and I don't want to trouble him by making him do all these formalities. Is it okay if I just book the hotels for the sake of applying for the tourist visa and then cancel the bookings? Do they follow up on such things? I need advice quickly.

Answer (score 3):

- You **may** change details of your itinerary after the visa is granted.
- You **may not** misrepresent the details of your itinerary to get a visa.

Telling one from the other depends on knowing *when* you made the decision, so the second point really becomes:

- You **should not** cause the perception that you misrepresented your itinerary.

There are stories of people who got their visa annulled for such a fake booking.

Comment: So does that mean that the embassy  followed up on some cases and found out that their bookings were fake and misleading?

Comment: @AyushmanSrivastav, apparently *some* embassies followed some cases.